# A generalization of a theorem about parallel lines in elementary geometry

Tags: geometry

A theorem in Euclid's Elements states that the line segment between the midpoints of two sides of a triangle is parallel to the third side and is half its length.  I have looked in various textbooks in geometry and have not found a generalization of this.  If $0 < p < 1$, such as $2/3$ or $\sqrt{2}/2$, and if $E$ and $F$ are points on sides $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$, respectively, of $\triangle{ABC}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\bigl\vert \overline{AE} \bigr\vert = p\bigl\vert \overline{AB} \bigr\vert
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\bigl\vert \overline{AF} \bigr\vert = p\bigl\vert \overline{AC} \bigr\vert ,
\end{equation*}
$\overline{EF}$ is parallel to $\overline{BC}$, and
\begin{equation*}
\bigl\vert \overline{EF} \bigr\vert = p\bigl\vert \overline{BC} \bigr\vert .
\end{equation*}
I would appreciate an explanation in the case that $p$ is a proper fraction.

Comment: It seems like it would suffice to consider similar triangles. Do you know what those are? Can you see why you get a triangle similar to your original one, just with sidelengths scaled by p?

Comment: @Improve  I am looking for an explanation that would fit just after the cited theorem regarding the line segment between the midpoints of two sides of a triangle.  The argument for that theorem involved the congruence of two triangles.

Comment: Do you agree why the line EF should be parallell to BC?

Comment: @Improve  In the case of midpoints, "yes."

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Parallel_Line_in_Triangle_Cuts_Sides_Proportionally

Comment: @Improve  Yep.  The statement is there.  I will look at it later.  It is interesting that the argument necessarily involves area.  I guess I was looking in the wrong parts of these geometry textbooks that I have.

Comment: For *rational* $p$ ---that is, $p = q/r$ where $q$ and $r$ are integers--- you can craft an argument that sub-divides the each side of the triangle into $r$ equal pieces. Connecting the various division points together appropriately forms what *appears to be* a triangular grid of $r^2$ congruent triangles, although it falls to you to prove that all the "grid lines" meet in the appropriate places and that the sub-triangles are in fact congruent. (The Midpoint Theorem itself helps show that, when applied systematically to various $2$-by-$2$ triangles in the "grid".) The result follows.